# Android: Prevent changing background color of text in TextView with ClickableSpan when touched

Tags: android, textview, clickable

I just want to make some text clickable in TextView, so I used `ClickableSpan`, but the background color of text is changed when I touched it.

This is my code:

```
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        // do something
    }
};
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("ClickableSpan Test");
ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, 13, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

How can I prevent changing background color on touch?

Comment: What color does it start with? What color does it show when clicked?

Comment: @Lee Jeongmin my answer is solution for your question then mark it right...

Comment: @Lokesh Yes your answer is solution. But I don't have enough reputation. So I can't do that. When I got a reputation, I will vote up your answer. Thank you again!

Comment: no man there is a right tick below vote count, please tick on that mark...it also increase your repo as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in you textview

```
android:textColorHighlight`="#000000"
```

Comment: what about no color? "@android:color/transparent" does not work